# C++ Have Function Accept types int and int[] using Templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have an existing code base with thousands of calls to `foo(int bar[],int type)` where in the function a number of structures are created where `x[i].bar=bar[i]` and `x[i].type=type`.
Now there's an edge case where I need to have different types for each `x`. So `foo(int bar[], int type[])` leads to `x[i].bar=bar[i]` and `x[i].type=type[i]`.

I currently have this implemented as an overload but that leads to a lot of copy pasted code. Is there a way to do this using templates?

Comment: Would template really solve this? You'd (probably) still need a specialization, can't you just refactor some of the duplicated code in its own function?

Comment: There is no real need for a template in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a third function, which is a "generalization" of the two. It should receive parameters of both "flavors", with a way to specify which flavor you want.

```
void foo_internal(int bar[], int type[], int default_type)
{
    ...
    x[i].bar = bar[i];
    x[i].type = (type == nullptr) ? default_type : type[i];
    ...
}
```

Put all your long code in there, then call it from both your overloads:

```
void foo(int bar[], int type[])
{
    foo_internal(bar, type, 0);
}

void foo(int bar[], int type)
{
    foo_internal(bar, nullptr, type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think the template could solve your problem, because a template function will be something like this

```
template<typename T>
void foo(int bar[],T type){
 ...
}
```

how do you manage to use **type** as int or int[] in generic way?

Instead you could refactor your code in order make **foo(int bar[],int type)** be used by **foo(int bar[],int[] type)**, doing something like this

```
void foo(int bar[],int type)
{
  ...
}

void foo(int bar[],int[] type)
{
  ...
  foo(bar,type[i]);
  ...
}
```

in this way, you should avoid to duplicate the code.